# Marshalling an IntPtr to a struct without knowing the type?

Tags: c#, pointers, pinvoke

I have an unmanaged function that takes an void pointer and a function pointer that takes a pointer as its argument. At some unknown time in the future, the function will be called with the void pointer. I am representing the function like so:

`public static extern void UseLater(IntPtr passedData, Action<IntPtr> function);`

However, I have a problem. While it is simple to copy a struct to an `IntPtr` for calling the function, I'm not sure how I can wrap the `Action<IntPtr>` as a function taking an `object`, the natural choice for data where the type doesn't need to be known. All of the methods relating to converting a pointer back to a struct require the type to be known. However, only the `Action<object>` needs to know what the `object` really is, and I'd like to avoid putting that information elsewhere. Is there some way I can turn the pointer into an `object` and pass it to the delegate?

Comment: If you know the length of the block of memory, you can take a copy of it, or indeed keep the original pointer to it so long as it remains valid. Then deserialize when you need to.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, but I'm trying to hide the pointers from the code that is customizeable (i.e. the Action<object>). Ideally I'd like to marshal it back and forth automatically and silently.

Comment: So what is stopping you?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I can't call PtrToStructure on the IntPtr without knowing the type of the object, but the whole point is that I shouldn't need to know it.

Comment: You do need to know the type. You can't unmarshal without knowing the type. I don't think you understand what PtrToStructure does.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It takes the region of memory that was allocated at the pointer, and copies it into an empty struct of the type you specify. I get it, but I'm trying to find some way around it.

Comment: Only if the struct is blittable does it do that. But even then you need to know the size of the type. And when you come to do something with it you've got to know the type. Suppose you have this thing in an `object`. Then what? There's no such thing as a typeless object.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The idea is for only the action to know the type of the object. It can cast its parameter to whatever it needs.

Comment: I already told you how to do that in my first comment

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Right, but that would mean passing an IntPtr to the Action instead of an object, no?

Comment: No. You can box anything. You need a pointer to unmanaged memory and the size. Or a byte array. And you'd need to know the type. Wrap that up in a structure or a class and you have what you need.